# How to add new row to datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have DataGridView filled with data from datasource (SQL). Now I want to a add new row, but I can't, because new data can't be added to bounded DataGridView...

I was trying to :

```
dataGridView1.Source = null;
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("1");
```

but it clears my previous data in table. How to do it, to add new row without deleting previous data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you set the [`DataSource` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) to `null`, you are essentially removing *all* data from the [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) (since it doesn't know what to bind to anymore).

You have two options here.  The first is to update the underlying data source.  Let's assume that it's a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx).  In this case, you'd do something like:

```
DataTable dt = dataGridView1.Source as DataTable;
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { ... });
```

And then the `DataGridView` will pick up on the changes (note that if you are not binding to something that doesn't implement the [`INotifyCollectionChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx), you'll have to call the [`ResetBindings` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resetbindings.aspx) to get the grid to refresh).

The other option is to let the `DataGridView` manage the rows.  You can do this by manually adding each item using the [`Add` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbs04kbx.aspx) on the [`DataGridViewRowCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.aspx) returned by the [`Rows` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx):

```
foreach (var item in source)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3", ...);
}
```

I wouldn't say the second solution is *optimal*, but it will work.

Finally, assuming you are binding to a `DataTable` (or some other materialization of the data from an underlying data source), this doesn't do anything about to updating underlying data source (that would be a separate question).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you don't.

When you set your `DataSource` to null, you've broken the link between your `DataGridView` and your data source, so its data won't be persisted.  You can't add a row to a bound `DataGridView` because it's supposed to represent the state of the underlying `DataSource`; you're effectively asking .net to make your table out of sync with its backing store, defeating the purpose of databinding in the first place.

If you want to add a row to the backing store, you should be adding a row in the `DataSource`, not in your `DataGridView`.

Comment: Tnx, can you show me how to add row to my DataSource? I have another DataGridView with data i'd like to add to my first GridView..

Comment: If your backing store is a SQL table, I'd imagine you'd just do an INSERT into that table.

Comment: It's not from SQL.. it's is some my data generated to add to first table and print it ;)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to do it manually and detailed? Something like this?

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = null;
        adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  WHERE", conn);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 5; //how many columns returns your SQL query? starts with 0

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "COl-1";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "COl-2";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "COl-3";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "COl-4";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "COl-5";

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(
            (dr["COL_HEADER_NAME1"].ToString()),
            (dr["COL_HEADER_NAME2"].ToString()),
            (dr["COL_HEADER_NAME3"].ToString()),
            (dr["COL_HEADER_NAME4"].ToString()),
            (dr["COL_HEADER_NAME5"].ToString()));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add rows by using add method of rows collection

```
me.datagridview1.rows.add("first","second","third");
```

You can add any amount of items with array collection.