# How to programmatically add a row to a datagridview when it is data-bound?

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I add a row to a datagridview control if it is bounded to a datasource (datatable) ? Thanks!

Comment: Add a row to the DataTable

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608647/how-to-add-new-row-to-datagridview?rq=1 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# How to add a new row to datagridview programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/c-sharp-how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add a row to the datatable, the datagridview will update automatically:

```
DataTable dt = myDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable;
//Create the new row
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

//Populate the row with data

//Add the row to data table
dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Note that you can also add at the top: `dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);`

Comment: best answer ever!

Answer (score 0):

- Create a class that corresponds to the data you want to display in your grid (same properties)
- In your data-binding function, get your query result, but put the result in a list (or any IEnumerable that suits you and the data binding)
- Create and add another object to your list according to your needs
- Bind the list

Answer (score 0):

// I manipulated a binding list. Here I was moving a row down in sequence.

```
BindingList<MyType> lst = (BindingList<MyType>)DataGridView.DataSource;
MyType objQcc = lst[rowIndex];
lst.Insert(rowIndex + 2, objQcc);
lst.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used dataset to add row to the datagridview if I try to add rows to the datagridview itself it says that it does not excepts adding rows programaticly because its databound.

**// DataSet of the datagridview can be found in the Form Load**

```
advokathusetDataSet.Kunde.Rows.Add(DeletedRowsList[lastindex].Cells[0].Value, DeletedRowsList[lastindex].Cells[1].Value, DeletedRowsList[lastindex].Cells[2].Value, DeletedRowsList[lastindex].Cells[3].Value, DeletedRowsList[lastindex].Cells[4].Value, DeletedRowsList[lastindex].Cells[5].Value, DeletedRowsList[lastindex].Cells[6].Value);
```

// Add row from Datagridview to list and Add row to datagridview from list - [How to add row to datagridview using list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759202/how-to-add-row-to-datagridview-using-list/61687205#61687205)