# How to retrieve data into a datagridview row by row from a SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I am working on a C# Windows Forms application. I need to retrieve data into a datagridview from a SQL Server database.

How my program works:

1. Enter product code in the textbox
2. Click on the "Display button"

Then product details (name & price) related to the product code are loading to the first row of the datagridview.

I need to load the data to the very next row when this is done with another code.

But the problem is retrieving data is loading only in the first row by overwriting existing data. Not loading row by row.

How can I get data to the next row when it is searched by a product code without losing existing data in the datagridview? Any help would be much appreciated.

[Image of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T02rR.png)

Here is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Retrieve_Data_In_Datagridview
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=InventoryManagement;Integrated Security=True");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bind_data()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [product_code], [product_name], [price], [discounted_price] FROM [product_tab] WHERE [product_code] = @parm1", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parm1", textBox1.Text);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Clear();
            da.Fill(dt);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            
            //DataGridView1 navigating to next row
            int nRow;
            nRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

            if (nRow < dataGridView1.RowCount)
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[++nRow].Cells[0];
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bind_data();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The line of code… `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` … is going to “replace” the existing grid data source with `dt`. If you want to “combine” the two tables I am guessing you could use the [DataTable.ImportRow(DataRow) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.importrow?view=net-5.0) to import all the rows from the query into the existing grid data source. Given this it appears you will need to create a “global” `DataTable` to bind to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is basically that each time you do: `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` you change the source to a new Datatable that contains only the result of the last query.
Here is something like what you need:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608647/how-to-add-new-row-to-datagridview]